# Loading an AngularJS directive after an already fully loaded controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I've got an AngularJS project in which I want to load a directive from a package X just after a controller from package Y will be fully loaded.

My main problem is that the controller is retrieving some data from a db and the directive needs that data to work as expected. Right now, the directive is finishing its loading before the data is fully loaded, so it doesn't work properly.

I need to get the directive starts to work when the controller (and what's more important, the data!) will be fully loaded.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make the "data" available via a promise, and use that promise within the directive to access the data when it's available?

Comment: If the directive is part of a different module, you can create a service to retrieve the data and have it return a `promise` in the `.run` block of the directive's module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem calls for working with promises.

[Angular's $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is based on [Kriskowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Also check out this video by the famouse Egghead for some extra information: [Egghead](https://thinkster.io/egghead/promises/).